# Python - data.to_csv output format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, aggregate

From a csv file having the following format:

```
Date,Data
01-01-01,111
02-02-02,222
03-03-03,333
```

I am calculating the monthly average of the values using the following code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
data['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data.reset_index()['Date']).month
mean_data = data.groupby('Month').mean()
```

Then I output a csv file using the following command:

```
mean_data.to_csv("test.csv")
```

It works fine and give me the following output:

```
Month,Data
01,01
02,02
03,03
04,04
...
```

But now I would like to know how many data have been included inside the monthly average calculation. For that I changed:

```
mean_data = data.groupby('Month').mean()
```

by:

```
mean_data = data.groupby(['Month']).agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

But the problem comes now. When I want to output the csv , I now have a weird format as follow:

```
      Data,Data,
      mean,count,
Month,
01,     01,8,
02,     02,9,
03,     03,7,
04,     04,5,
```

Which is not really convenient. Instead I would like to have the following output:

```
Month,Mean,Count
01,01,8
02,02,9
03,03,7
04,04,5
```

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Comment: Please edit your example to be reproducible. `Month,Data=01,01` does not look like the right output value.

Comment: Ah, you're only concerned with the column name header: `Month, Data mean, Data count...`

Comment: @smci - I am actually concern by this blank space and the two line header, which is not really convenient when I want to re-read the data afterwards.

Comment: Ok but the point is the title is misleading, this is not so much about `to_csv`, more about the annoying default column names pandas gave the aggregate with multiple functions, at least your code not jezrael's. Suggest you edit the title to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need specify column after `groupby`:

```
#convert first column to datetime
data = pd.read_csv("input.csv", parse_dates=[0])
```

---

```
df['Month'] = df['Date'].dt.month
mean_data = data.groupby('Month')['Data'].agg(['mean', 'count'])
```

should be simplify:

```
mean_data = data.groupby(df['Date'].dt.month)['Data'].agg(['mean', 'count'])
```